# Spring security mapping

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, spring-security

I want to limit access to my file uploading functionality. I wrote intercept url in security file, but Spring Security doesn't map this URL. I use 3.0.3 version of spring security.
These are my xml files :

`security.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

    <security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/forbidden.jsp">
        <intercept-url pattern="/files/**"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" filters="none"/>
        <form-login login-page="/login.htm" 
                    authentication-failure-url = "/login.htm?login_error=1" 
                    default-target-url="/forbidden.htm"/>
        <logout logout-success-url="/login.htm" />
        <anonymous username="guest" granted-authority="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />
        <remember-me />
    </http>


    <beans:bean id="accountService" name="accountService" class="com.demo.service.impl.AccountServiceImpl" />

    <beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="accountService"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="accountService" />
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

`dispatcher-servlet.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.demo"/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />


    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <bean id="multipartResolver"
       class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"/>


</beans>
```

`web.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:/application-dao.xml
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
            /WEB-INF/security.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
<!--     Spring Security -->
  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why do you think that Spring doesn't map your URL?

At first glance mapping looks good, but `intercept-url` is not complete. To give access to URL for someone you should point the rule at `access` attribute. So correct interceptor will looks like this:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/files/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
```

In this particular case only authenticated users will have access to your URL.

More about basic Spring Security features you can read at [official tutorial](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/tutorial.html).

Comment: Good answer, it should be noted that when coming from the config of the question adding the access attribute is more like restricting access, since there are currently no restrictions. Also standard approach should be to restrict access for a areas by default and then only grant access when necessary.

Comment: Thank for the solution, @Maksim Kolesnikov. I tried this solution and security began to work.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing your namespace on your security tags, I see they are declared as "security", and your intercept tags are missing this namespace